# I want to collect websocket data from coinbase pro and put it in a dataframe. Trying to find a way to collect the output from this code?

Tags: python, database, websocket, python-asyncio, event-loop

I'm using [copra](https://github.com/tpodlaski/copra) to receive live data from Coinbase Pro. This code starts outputting the websocket feed. I have no clue how to collect the data in a variable and make a df with it?? End goal is to put it in a database.

Objective:

- Collect Data from WebSocket feed in 5 minute increments(OHLCV Purposes)
- Put each 5 minute collection in their own DataFrame
- Create OHLCV 5-min candles with that DataFrame
- Send OHLCV data to a PostgreSQL DataBase

```
import asyncio

from copra.websocket import Channel, Client

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

ws = Client(loop, Channel('matches', 'BTC-USD'))


async def work():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(30)
        print("Task Executed")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    asyncio.ensure_future(work())
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    print("Closing Loop")
    loop.close()
```

Example Output:

```
{'type': 'match', 'trade_id': 75894771, 'maker_order_id': '9742d468-770d-4403-82fc-23b87ce6aa9d', 'taker_order_id': 'f76e05d1-c206-4482-bce1-9763c73970d0', 'side': 'sell', 'size': '0.00280190', 'price': '8348.99', 'product_id': 'BTC-USD', 'sequence': 11001219347, 'time': '2019-10-13T01:59:42.814000Z'}
{'type': 'match', 'trade_id': 75894772, 'maker_order_id': '9742d468-770d-4403-82fc-23b87ce6aa9d', 'taker_order_id': '391c748a-ca33-4a11-9a9d-bbe3565e643e', 'side': 'sell', 'size': '0.00256354', 'price': '8348.99', 'product_id': 'BTC-USD', 'sequence': 11001219566, 'time': '2019-10-13T01:59:43.827000Z'}
{'type': 'match', 'trade_id': 75894773, 'maker_order_id': 'af29c906-be3d-41ca-904b-b87a7bb2270d', 'taker_order_id': 'a9a5ed9b-b83e-4408-bfb6-62b0dad6fce6', 'side': 'sell', 'size': '0.00400000', 'price': '8349.48', 'product_id': 'BTC-USD', 'sequence': 11001220104, 'time': '2019-10-13T01:59:45.944000Z'}
```